# Windows 10 SDK hangs and wont go any further

Tags: windows-10-sdk

I downloaded .exe file from Microsoft site about Windows 10 SDK, and after a long installing process it just hang,
as seen on this screen

[image: 1]

does it need this much time to install? or is it stuck completly? and what to do about it?

i need it to use C++ with Visual Studio but it looks like the installation is stuck again (tried many times)